# How to re-order HTML via Javascript/ JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have the following in my HTML. `<div class="header">` appear on top of the page. I would like to place it just after the footer `<div class="footer">` if the page is displaying on a mobile device.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){   
        var isMobile = false; //initiate as false
   // device detection
   if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|ipad|iris|kindle|Android|Silk|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(navigator.userAgent) 
   || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(navigator.userAgent.substr(0,4))) {
   isMobile = true;
   }

   if (is_mobile == true) {
          $( "footer" ).first().after( $( "header" ) );
      }

   });
</script>
```

This attempt does not make any changes in the HTML ordering. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the developer console?

Comment: Is the footer CSS fixed?

Comment: No. footer is not fixed, and I do not get any errors.

Comment: I would use the document resize function and then test for desired screen size.  It's more of a responsive method vs actually detecting devices.

Comment: Device sniffing is never a good pattern to follow. While you can't move elements directly in CSS, you can make them appear in other places if you use absolute positioning. For that reason I'd suggest you use a stylesheet with a media rule for small devices to re-organise your page. It would perform better, be more reliable and future proof, not to mention a better separation of concerns.

Comment: Q: What am I doing wrong? A: Device detection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the dots are missing in your selectors.

Try this:

```
$( ".footer" ).first().after( $( ".header" ) );
```

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend you to use Media Queries over jquery for this purpose

```
/* For mobile phones: */
.header-top {
    display:block;
}
.header-bottom {
    display:none;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    /* For tablets: */
    .header-top {
    display:block;
    }
    .header-bottom {
    display:none;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    /* For desktop: */
    .header-top {
    display:none;
    }
   .header-bottom {
    display:block;
    }
}
```

for more info:
[Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)